# Можно ли интегрировать задачи по программированию в редактор кода/IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

Время от времени решаю задачи по программированию на различных ресурсах типа `codewars`, `project Euler`. Их небольшой недостаток - лишь базовые возможности автоподстановки и нет отладки. Поэтому часто копирую задачу в обычный редактор кода и уже там решаю. Интересно, есть ли возможность интегрировать задачи с какого-то из популярных сервисом с задачами по одной или сразу пакетом, чтоб можно было спокойно порешать в редакторе типа `atom`, `IDEA`, `netbeans` или аналогичных. подобный есть для `python` - [https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7991-checkio](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7991-checkio-plugin-for-pycharm-edu)-... но хочу попрактиковаться с другими языками

Comment: С чем вы хотите "интегрировать задачи" и как вы себе это представляете?